# Changing CNAME destination to an S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns, cname, bucket

I have an AWS S3 bucket named **a.example.com** which is hosting a static website.

Currently the CNAME DNS record for domain `a.example.com` points to `a.example.com.s3-website.us-east-2.amazonaws.com`.

Now I want to change the CNAME from **a** to **b** so that domain **b.example.com** should point to the same  bucket, which will remain unchanged as `a.example.com.s3-website.us-east-2.amazonaws.com`.

- Can I simply change the CNAME to make it work?
- Does something else in AWS S3 Bucket Dashboard need changing too?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change only the CNAME from **a** to **b** so that domain **b.example.com** should point to the same bucket. You do not have any change in Amazon site, you only need to point your new hostname to the old bucket.

Comment: I did that (changed CNAME only) but now visiting **b.example.com** shows this `404 Not Found Code: NoSuchBucket Message: The specified bucket does not exist`. So doing just that is not working, right?

Comment: do you resolve the same IP for  b.example.com and a.example.com.s3-website.us-east-2.amazonaws.com

Comment: How do I check that, please? Thanks.

Comment: `nslookup b.example.com` and `nslookup a.example.com.s3-website.us-east-2.amazonaws.com`

Comment: OK, checked, and no the IPs are totally different.

Comment: did you reload the dns server?

Comment: DNS server at my local machine (ipconfig/flushdns?), or b.example.com (which I can't), or AWS (which I can't either)? Thanks.